# Fast way to cluster time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to cluster time-series data: I have about 16000 time-series vectors, each vector is ~1500 samples long.

I tried using the **dtw** package:

```
d = dist(x = time_series, method = "DTW")
hclust(d)
```

however the distance matrix calculation didn't finish running throughout the whole weekend.

I'm looking for a faster way since my data set will be much larger.

Answer (score 3):

Your data is on length 1500. Suppose it is oversampled..

If you downsample it 1 in 2, DTW will be 4 times faster.
If you downsample it 1 in 4, DTW will be 16 times faster.
If you downsample it 1 in 10, DTW will be 100 times faster.

This might be a good starting point.

Are you using cDTW or DTW?  The former is significant faster, and can often be more accurate.

A paper in SIGKDD this week has a faster way to cluster DTW by using upper and lower bounds [a].

---

However, your matrix is of size  (16000 * 15999)/2.

So if you have two days: two days / (16000 * 15999)/2 =  337 microseconds

So you need to do each comparison in  337 microseconds, that is not a lot of time. This will be difficult..., but it is doable with effort. If you get stuck, email me (I am the last author of [a])

[a] Nurjahan Begum, Liudmila Ulanova, Jun Wang, Eamonn Keogh (2015). Accelerating Dynamic Time Warping Clustering with a Novel Admissible Pruning Strategy  SIGKDD 2015